# Влияет ли else if на читаемость кода?

Tags: if, логика

Есть условие:

```
bool a = randBool();
bool b = randBool();

if (a && !b) {
   ...
} else if (a && b) {
   ...
}
```

Понятно, что если программа дошла до `else if` и `a == true`, то выходит, что  `b == true`, а значит и `a && b` с точки зрения логики бессмысленно указывать. То есть это можно написать так:

```
if (a && !b) {
   ...
} else if (a) {
   ...
}
```

Но на мой взгляд, не указывать `b` - вредит читаемости кода в промышленной разработке.

Как вам кажется, есть ли смысл ради читаемости кода указывать `b` в `else if`?

.

Comment: Нет смысла, кмк.

Comment: Если вложений несколько, применяйте `Select Case`(`switch`), читаемость кода улучшится

Comment: Имхо, смысл есть, через день/неделю/месяц внезапно появится требование обрабатывать так же и ситуацию `a && b && c`. В первом варианте достаточно будет добавить совершенно аналогичный блок `else if`, во втором - еще и переписывать условие в предыдущем блоке.

Comment: соглашусь с @vikttur select case и комментарий достаточно, чтобы понять код спустя даже пару лет. а более правильные названия переменных, позволяют еще быстрее понять код

Comment: Есть смысл в том случае, если вам это в глаза бросается. По сути, бессмысленный вопрос, как и его суть